# Spark Datasets available in Python?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

[Here](https://www.databricks.com/spark/getting-started-with-apache-spark/datasets), it is stated:

> ..you can create Datasets within a Scala or Python..

while [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#:%7E:text=A%20Dataset%20is%20a%20distributed,Spark%20SQL%27s%20optimized%20execution%20engine.), the following is stated:

> Python does not have the support for the Dataset API

Are datasets available in python?

Comment: Are datasets available in python? Well not directly, there are a couple of modules you can try out

`pip install load_dataset`
`pip install imbalanced_databases`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the question is about Typed Spark Datasets.

If so, then the answer is no.

Mentioned spark datasets are only available in Scala and Java.

In Python implementation of Spark (or PySpark) you have to choose between DataFrames as the preferred choice and RDD.

Reference:
[RDD vs. DataFrame vs. Dataset](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset)

Update 2022-09-26: Clarification regarding typed spark datasets

Comment: So this is an error in the docu?

Comment: I think that article brings some confusion about the concept of a Spark Dataset. We all treat datasets as compilation time typed data objects. Compilation time typing is not even possible in Python due to the nature of the Python as the language.

Comment: Therefore, the article mixes dataframes, datasets and call them both as datasets. Perhaps it is not that far from the truth though, since DataFrame is untyped dataset

Comment: Dataframe if just a type of Dataset in Spark. in the implementation, Dataframe is defined as Dataset[Row] where an instance of a Row contains one record(line) in your Dataframe. Since in PySpark you have Dataframe available, you can say that youhave dataset in PySpark. the point is the APIs of Dataframe and Dataset are quite similair, you can use them as a one( ofc Dataframe is less typed but that's because of python language)

Answer (score 1):

As Alexander says, Spark only implements the DataSet API in Scala and Java. However, you can achieve a similar effect using the Python package `typedspark`.

```
from typedspark import Column, DataSet, Schema
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType, StringType

class Person(Schema):
    id: Column[LongType]
    name: Column[StringType]
    age: Column[LongType]

def foo(df: DataSet[Person]) -> DataSet[Person]:
    # do stuff
    return df
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of typedspark. You can find more at:

- https://github.com/kaiko-ai/typedspark
- https://typedspark.readthedocs.io