# How to create dataset in pyspark

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, dataset, bigdata

I would like to use dataset in pyspark . I read pyspark doesnt support dataset and only Java / Scala support dataset .

Is there any way I can use Dataset in pyspark ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Datasets available in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840095/spark-datasets-available-in-python)

Comment: You can use spark dataframe and you can keep collection of dataframes with usage standard python collections

Answer (score 0):

If you thinking about Typed Spark Datasets, then no, you can't use them in python.

Check **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840095/spark-datasets-available-in-python)**.